# Array of Strings

Tags: c, string, multidimensional-array

I have an interesting problem.

I define,

```
typedef char *string;

char array[10];    
string buf[10];  
i=0;  
while(1){    
  array=<assign_string>       
  buf[i]= array;        
  i++;
}
```

At each iteration i assign different strings. For instance,
buf[0] should be "1111111111"
buf[1] should be "2222222222" and so on.
However when i assign "2222222222" when i=1, buf[0] also changes to "2222222222". What could be the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that all entries in `buf` point to the same string - the one named `array`. So changing `array` will affect all `buf` entries.

You could fix this by allocating a new string for every iteration, e.g. your pseudo-code would become:

```
string buf[10];  
i=0;  
while(1){    
  buf[i]= strdup( <array_string> );
  i++;
}
```

Make sure to `free()` all the strings when you're done using them.

Comment: btw, your "typedef char *string;" has hidden the problem. That's exactly why a "char *" is NOT a string in C. In C, there is no data type "string".

Answer (score 0):

You are probably not allocating a new string for each entry in buf. Instead you are saving a reference to the same string in each buf entry.

Answer (score 0):

When you do `buf[i]=array;` you put the address of your `char array[10]` into `buf[i]`.
No suprise, each `buf[i]` has the same address and the same value.